# Serialising fabricjs canvas with references to other objects

Tags: json, fabricjs

Based on the explanation [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3)

of how to use json with fabricjs I've written some code to serialise and deserialise my fabricjs canvas. But it doesn't work and I think the difficulty is that my lines have triangle properties. When deserialising a line, the relevant triangle may not yet exist, so I'm not surprised that they seem to be unrelated to the lines after this is done. How do I resolve this? Should I give each triangle a name so that I can find it after deserialisation and set it to be the appropriate triangle for the line? Or is subclassing the way forward? Thanks.

```
var line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 0, 0], {
        fill: '#444',
        stroke: '#444',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        id: 'arrow',
        name: 'arrow',
        selectable: true,       //if turn this off hovercursor doesn't work. So arrow is selectable. But setting hasBorders to false stops blue rectangle appearing around it so there's no problem.
        lockMovementX: true,
        lockMovementY: true,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        strokeDashArray:[10,5],
        hasControls: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        hasBorders: false,
        sourceObject: sourceObject,
        targetObject: targetObject,
        offset: offset,
        cornerColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
        stateProperties: ['triangle'],
    });

    /** [Create triangle attached to the end of the line  */
    line.triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        selectable: true,
        hasBorders: true,
        hasControls: true,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        hasControls: false,
        lockRotation: true,
        pointType: 'arrow_start',
        width: TRI_WIDTH,
        height: TRI_HEIGHT,
        fill: '#444',
        selectable: false,
    });

    setxy(line, offset);

    line.toObject = (function(toObject) {
      return function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
          triangle: this.triangle
        });
      };
    })(line.toObject);

    canvas.add(line, line.triangle);
```

Comment: Edit: In fact other things aren't restored either, like cornerColor. Not sure what I have to do about that.

Comment: OK, so I've found that it seems that certain properties are serialised by fabricjs and certain ones aren't. I can get cornerColor to serialise by adding it to the line.toObject override as "cornerColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',". That's easy enough, although it feels that it shouldn't be necessary. I'm still working on getting the objects to relate to each other - the only way I can see is to give each one a tag and loop through them on deserialising to find the relevant one.

Comment: Also, what is the significance of the "(line.toObject)" expression at the end of the line.toObject declaration? This seems like very odd syntax to me.